# Does Hadoop come handy in my project?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, hadoop, bigdata

A couple days ago I was asked by my company to find requirements to start a project. The project is creating an e-book store. The term simple, but the total amount of data is about 4TB and the number of files are around 500,000.

As my team members use php and mysql, I tried to look around apache for big data. I obviously faced apache haadoop, and mysql-cluster for big data. But after several days of digging on google, I'm now just completely confused! I now have these questions:

1. Are even these amount of data (4-5TB) considered as big data? (Some sources said that at least 5TB of data should use hadoop, some other said big data for hadoop mean Zetabytes and Petabytes)
2. Does hadoop ship with it's own special database, or should be used with mysql or etc.?
3. Does hadoop works only on a cluster, or it works on a single-nod server as fine?

As I faced these terms very recent, I believe that some or all of my questions maybe really silly... But I'll be really grateful if you have other suggestions for this type project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my short answers

- Are even these amount of data (4-5TB) considered as big data? (Some sources said that at least 5TB of data should use hadoop, some other said big data for hadoop mean Zetabytes and Petabytes)

  - Yes and no. For certain usecases, this is not big enough data while for others, it is. Questions that should be asked and answered
  - Is this data is growing. What is the rate of growth.
  - Are you going to run some analytics on this data from time to time
- Does hadoop ship with it's own special database, or should be used with mysql or etc.?

  - Yes, Hadoop has HDFS file system, which can store flatfile and can be treated like data repository. But that may not be the best solution. You may want to look at NoSQL DBs like Cassandra, HBase, MongoDB
- Does hadoop works only on a cluster, or it works on a single-nod server as fine?

  - Technically, yes, hadoop can run on a single nod in Pseudo cluster or standalone mode. But that is used only for learning or testing purpose for development. For any production environment you should think of Hadoop clusters spanning multiple VMs.... Minimum I saw in prod was 6 VM.

As such 5TB is not very big volume for Relational DB (that supports clustering). But cost of supporting relational DB goes up exponentially with capacity. While with Hadoop and just HDFS, the cost is very low.... add Cassandra or HBase...not much difference. But remember, simply using hadoop, you are looking at a high latency system. If your expectation is that Hadoop will answer your queries in real time ...please look out for other solutions. (eg:queries like list all books checked out to Xyz", then just get it from DB... don't use Hadoop for that query).

Overall my suggestion will be, take a crash course on Hadoop from youtube, cloudera, try to gain some expertise on what is Hadoop and what is not and then decide. Your questions gives an impression , that you have a long learning curve ahead and it is worth taking that challenge.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but it is too long.

Hadoop is a framework for writing parallel software, originally written by Yahoo.  It is loosely based on a framework developed at Google in the 1990s, which in turn was a parallel implementation of map-reduce primitives from the Lisp language. You can think of Hadoop as a bunch of libraries that run either on hardware you own or on hardware on the cloud.  These libraries provide a programming interface to java and to other languages.  It allows you to take advantage of a cluster of processors and disks (with HDFS).  Its major features are scalability and fault tolerance, both very important for large data problems.

Hadoop implements a programming methodology build around a parallel implementation of map-reduce.  That was the *original* application.  Nowadays, lots of things are built on Hadoop.  You should start with the [Apache project description](http://hadoop.apache.org/) and [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop) to learn more.

Several databases support interfaces to Hadoop (Asterdata comes to mind).  Often when one thinks of "databases" and "Hadoop", one is thinking of Pig or Hive or some related open-source project.

As for your question.  If your data conforms naturally to a relational database (table with columns connected by keys) then use a relational database.  If you need fast performance on web applications with hierarchical data, then learn about NoSQL solutions, such as MongoDB.  If your data has a complex structure and requires scalability *and* you have programming skills on your team, then think about a Hadoop-based component to the solution.  And, for a large project, multiple technologies are often needed for different components -- real time operations using NoSQL, reporting using SQL, ad hoc querying using a combination of SQL and Hadoop (for instance).